# Protractor and reducing .all elements list

Tags: filter, protractor, reduce

I completely don't know why searching through `.all` list using `.filter` gives me a ElementFinder that I can chain with `.click`

```
function findElem(name) {
    return elemList.filter(function(elem, idx) {
        return elem.element(by.css('some css here').getText().then(function(text) {
           return text === name;
        });
    }).first();
}
```

but when sue similar but with `reduce` like this:

```
function findElem(name, findPosition) {
    return elemList.reduce(function(total, current, idx) {
        return current.element(by.css('some css here').getText().then(function(text) {
            if (text ==== name) {
               return findPosition === undefined ? current : idx;
            } else {
               return total;
            }
        });
    });
}
```

even if I get the same ElementFinder (at least in console.log) I cannot use it with `.click` and have error that `pageObject.findElem('name of element to find').click is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
function findElem(name, findPosition) {
  return elemList.reduce((total, current, idx) => {
    return current.$('some css here').getText()
      .then((text) => {
        if (text === name) {
          return findPosition === undefined ? current : idx;
        } else {
          return total;
        }
      });
  });
}
```

The `error pageObject.findElem('name of element to find').click is not a function` appears because return value isn't an `ElementFinder`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Oleksii for nice addition but this function is working perfectly :-) 
I just used it wrongly on later stage.